# Binning labels and edges error

Tags: label, binning, edges

Made bins "low","medium","high" for column price but while using the pd.cut function I am getting this error. I do not understand what this error means and the meaning of bin edges as well. Have attached the screenshot of the error code.

[image: Here is the whole script for binning]

Kindly help me understand it.

Comment: Post the code as text rather than image, it will be easier to read and fix.

Comment: @EzLo it is not able to format my code hence not able to post it as text. Plus I guess you would need the whole script for this line of code to understand where I am going wrong.